# How to push values into an array on submit btn click (react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a questions form with custom inputs.

```
const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label className={classes.label}>{props.label}
            <input className={classes.input} {...props}/>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I get question list from server and set them into `questions`. Then I create a form for answer to these questions.

```
<form onSubmit = {onAnswersSubmit}>
     {questions?.map((item) =>
         <Input key={item.id} id={item.id} label={item.question}/>)}
      <Button> Submit </Button>
</form>
```

I'd like to push answers from inputs into array on submit button click, but have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use state for this. One state for the array (I've called it `state`), and another to capture the answers to the questions (an object).

When an input's `onChange` listener is fired it calls `handleChange`. This function takes the name and value from the input (note: this example assumes that you can add a `name` property to the data you receive from your server), and then updates the `answers` state.

When the button is clicked the completed `answers` state (an object) gets added to the main state array.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  // Initialise the states
  const [ state, setState ] = useState([]);
  const [ answers, setAnswers ] = useState({});

  // Push the completed answers object into
  // the state array, then reset the answers state
  function handleClick() {
    setState([ ...state, answers ]);
    setAnswers({});
  }

  // Get the name and value from the input
  // and update the answers state
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setAnswers({ ...answers, [name]: value });
  }

  // Log the main state when it changes
  useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(obj => {
        const { id, name, question } = obj;
        return (
          <input
            key={id}
            name={name}
            placeholder={question}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );

}

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'name', question: 'What is your name?' },
  { id: 2, name: 'age', question: 'How old are you?' },
  { id: 3, name: 'location', question: 'Where do you live?' }  
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html `input`'s `onChange` prop and pass an onChange function from your parent form to handle that like so:

```
// This is assuming this is inside a functional component

const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

const onAnswerChange = useCallback((index, answer) => {
  setAnswers((oldAnswers) => {
    oldAnswers[index] = answer;
    return oldAnswers;
  });
}, [setAnswers]);

return 
<form onSubmit = {onAnswersSubmit}>
     {questions?.map((item, index) =>
         <Input key={item.id} 
                id={item.id} 
                label={item.question}
                value={answers[index] ?? ''}
                onChange={(e) => onAnswerChange(index, evt.target.value)}/>)}
      <Button> Submit </Button>
</form>
```

Then you can use the stored state in `answers` as part of your onAnswersSubmit callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

const handleAnswerChange = (index, answer) => {
    let olddata=answers;
    olddata[index]=answer;
    setAnswers([...olddata]);
}


const Input = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label className={classes.label}>{props.label}
            <input className={classes.input} {...props}/>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};

<form onSubmit = {onAnswersSubmit}>
     {questions?.map((item) =>
         <Input key={item.id} id={item.id} label={item.question} onChange={handleAnswerChange}/>)}
      <Button> Submit </Button>
</form>
```